# Android: Periodic work manager that repeats on certain days or dates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, reminders

I want to build a work manager that sends users a notification at certain times. The repeating criterias are the following:

- a notification every week, on TUESDAY at 14:30
- a notification every month, o the 15th of that month, having a repeat count of only 6 times

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set an exact time so no periodic work is possible. You have to recalculate every time:

Do something like this by using "**setInitialDelay**":

```
fun  setupWork(){
        if (isCountLimitReached()) {
            return
        }
        
        val workRequest: WorkRequest =
                OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
                        .setInitialDelay(getNextInterval(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build()
        updateCount()
        WorkManager
                .getInstance(context)
                // Make sure you have only one work like that.
                .enqueueUniqueWork(
                        "MY_WORK_UNIQUE_NAME",
                        // If there is existing work like this - replace it.
                        ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                        workRequest
                )
    }

    fun getNextInterval(): Long {
        TODO("Get milliseconds from 'execution date' and subtract 'now'")
    }
    
    private fun updateCount(){
        TODO("Use SharedPreferences or something like this")
    }
    
    private fun isCountLimitReached(): Boolean {
        TODO("Use SharedPreferences or something like this")
    }
```